# Sync comments between two WP installs

Tags: comments

Either with a SQL script or a plugin, I'm looking to create a copy of a site and to syncronize the comments between both sites. One of the sites will have certain comments that are private so they will not be synced.

I was deciding whether to go with Intense Debate so that I could somehow configure a comments template to sync across pages. Can this be done across separate sites? Or would a third-party plugin be a better choice?

---

Updated Question: How can you use:

```
comments_template($file)
```

Where ($file) lives on a different server? Obviously I'm going to run into security problems but is there a way you can access a different WP database?

Comment: `$file !== database` - what _exactly_ do you want?

Comment: I need the wp_comments table of two separate WP sites to talk to each other so that they are synchronized. The function would check for comment_post_id and if they match, the synchronization would start.

Comment: What does `comments_template()` and the `$file` have to do with DB synchronization?

Comment: Well, using the same $file with an absolute uri suggests that the comments are synced. That's what I got from your answer. I think my original question was misleading because I used the word "template". That's a no-no. I need the DB's to be synced. So should I be looking at replication rules?

Comment: I thought you want to have the same files, nothing else. Sharing a [user table](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/synchronize-wordpress-user-accounts-across-multiple-domains-and-installations-wi) is possible, but not recommended. Sharing comments isn't possible.

Comment: "Sharing comments isn't possible." Even if I were to sync users, and then append comments on each site? The most important pieces of information are the actual comment, the date, and the author. I don't care about session IDs or anything else. There must be a way.

Comment: What if, on submission of a comment, you add an action that connects to the second WP site and add the comment to the appropriate post...http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database

Comment: I don't know about that. You'll have to try and share your experiences here.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sharing the template

Just define it inside your template with [`comments_template( $file );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template).

#### Sharing the DB table

… simply said: It's not possible. You can share the [user table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/synchronize-wordpress-user-accounts-across-multiple-domains-and-installations-wi), which isn't recommended.

Comment: Do you mean: create a copy of the comments.php and call it something else? I'm not quite sure what the argument would be. I want to create a unison parent for the comments to link to.

Comment: Sry, but I don't understand a single word. What's a "unison parent for the comments to link to"??

Comment: Say you have two pages. Each would normally have their own set of comments. Is there a way to share the comments database between the two tables?

Comment: Can this be done across two separate WP installs?

Comment: I'm note really sure about this. It depends on your server setup. Anyway, you'll need to setup an absolute uri, which is only possible, using the `comments_template` filter, that (guess what), filters the complete uri, not only the file relative from the stylesheet files root dir.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Sorry for the earlier gibberish, I've come a long way in a month.

Comment: To add to this, is there a way to provide two-way synchronization? You can define comments_template( file1 ) and then both sites would show file1. But if you update file2 (or site2) with new comments, then file1 will not receive those updates. I'm thinking a MySQL update script would be the only option.

Comment: I know, that I've already written this as comment here, but ... _Sry, but I don't understand a single word_.

Comment: See my updated question above.